# Use lapack library in java as in .NET

Tags: java, .net, lapack

Is it possible to have the power of [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) in java?

I have used some compiled binaries in windows to use in .NET, but to use it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [netlib-java](http://code.google.com/p/netlib-java/) project which provides flexible wrappers which let you use the FORTRAN versions of BLAS, LAPACK, etc, via JNI, or a Java implementation of LAPACK.